# Crashes in Android 6.0.1 after restart because of Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras()

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, parameter-passing

I am trying retrieve variables with this code

Here's my `MainActivity`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  String Variable1 = null;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
      Variable1 = extras.getString("Variable1");
      EditText1_ET.setText(Variable1);
    }
  }
}
```

I am creating `Variable1` in another `Activity`

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
i.putExtra("Variable1", textview.getText().toString());
startActivity(i);
```

Its working great until I reboot OS (Android 6.0.1) and start my app, I get error that my app stopped working.

I tried it on Android 5.1 and its working without error.

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Well it is better to change the following:

```
SearchQueryTerm = extras.getString("Variable1");
EditText1_ET.setText(Variable1);
```

to:

```
Variable1 = extras.getString("Variable1");
if(EditText1_ET != null) {EditText1_ET.setText(Variable1);}
```

in your code you just assign `null` to your `EditText` every time.

Answer (score 0):

You should do this, and check for nullability :

```
if (extras != null) {
String variable1 = extras.getString("Variable1");
  if (variable1 != null) {
    EditText EditText1_ET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.xxxx);
    if (EditText1_ET != null)
        EditText1_ET.setText(variable1);
  }
}
```

Also init your EdiText variable before setting text !

Comment: cool, consider marking answer as the correct one to help others facing similar issue !

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've solved your problem. Yet, I though I need to put my suggestion here.

From the `Activity2` where you're passing the parameter value, do you really need to get the text from a `TextView`? Because, you already have set some `String` value in your `TextView` somewhere. Just use that `String` variable to pass the value to another `Activity`.

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
i.putExtra("Variable1", myString);
startActivity(i);
```

Now in the `MainActivity`, check if the `Variable1` is `null` and initialize your `EditText` first.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  String Variable1 = null;
  private EditText EditText1_ET;  // Declare an EditText first

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Initialize your EditText here
    EditText1_ET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.your_edit_text_id);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
      Variable1 = extras.getString("Variable1");

      // Here check if Variable1 is null
      if(Variable1 != null) EditText1_ET.setText(Variable1);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Had the same problem, it was still crashing even after checking for null.

I used a **try-catch block** and that solved the problem for me.